# In Python, command line args without import?

Tags: python, console, arguments, args

In Python, is it possible to get the command line arguments without importing sys (or any other module)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some dirty hack that makes this possible. Especially if the requirements are imprecise...

Comment: First of all, there may be a reference to sys in some builtin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you're using Linux.

If you know the process ID, you can read its `/proc/{pid}/cmdline` file, which contains a null-separated list of the command line arguments:

```
PROCESS_ID = 14766
cmdline = open("/proc/" + str(pid) + "/cmdline").read()
print cmdline.split("\0")
```

But it's hard to know the process ID before you start the process. But there's a solution! Look at ALL of the processes!

```
PROGRAM_NAME = "python2\0stack.py"
MAX_PID = int(open("/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max").read())    

for pid in xrange(MAX_PID):
    try:
        cmd = open("/proc/" + str(pid) + "/cmdline").read().strip("\0")
        if PROGRAM_NAME in cmd:
            print cmd.split("\0")
            break
    except IOError:
        continue
```

So if we run `python2 stack.py arg1 arg2 arg3` at the shell, a list of the command line arguments will be printed. This assumes you only ever have one process running the script at a given time.

PS., `MAX_PID` is the maximum PID on your system. You can find it in `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`.

PPS. Never, *ever*, **ever** write code like this. This post was 49% joke.

Comment: I was hoping for some clever solutions like this! Thanks! :)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use `/proc/self`? The answer appears to just be: `open('/proc/self/cmdline').read().split('\0')`. `man proc` does not mention when it was added, but `/proc/self` was referenced [in this question two years before this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34192/how-is-proc-self-implemented-in-linux) so it doesn't appear to be very new.

Answer (score 1):

No. You must import `sys` to get [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), which is where the arguments are located

Answer (score 1):

No. Command line arguments are available only in `sys.argv` which cannot be accessed without importing `sys`.
May I ask why do you not want to import sys?

Comment: Does not answer the question and requests clarification, this is not an answer but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, this will give you an array identical to the one that `sys.argv` would return:

```
argv = open('/proc/self/cmdline').read().split('\0')
```