# Python: Find `sys.argv` before the `sys` module is loaded

Tags: python, python-2.6

I want to find the command line arguments that my program was called with, i.e. `sys.argv`, but I want to do that before Python makes `sys.argv` available. This is because I'm running code in `usercustomize.py` which is imported by the `site` module, which is imported before Python populates `sys.argv`. (If you're curious, the reason I'm doing this is to start my debugger without changing my program code.)

Is there any way to find the command line arguments without `sys.argv`?

Also: The solution needs to work for Python 2.6 :(

Comment: Can you use `ctypes`?  If not, what Python modules *can* you use?  Can you use self-made modules written in C?

Comment: *“the reason I'm doing this is to start my debugger without changing my program code”* – Can you expand on that? I’m sure there *must be a better way™*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, command line args without import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368283/in-python-command-line-args-without-import)

Comment: I'm assuming there is a reason, so if you absolutely have to do this you can write a wrapper module that calls your code in a nicer way

Comment: > I'm doing this is to start my debugger < You can execute arbitary python code from gdb attached to CPython interptreter. I.e. `p PyRun_SimpleString("print globals()")` (but you'll have to break at `PyEval_EvalFrameEx` first)

Comment: Are you looking for an easy to write user-friendly command-line interface using a different library (API)?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Python uses such libraries as sys, os, and etc to get access to system variables and os functional. It can't do it with just core functions. So, in any case, you need to import sys.