# How can I get the python script path from a python interpreter command line?

Tags: python

related: [Python: Find `sys.argv` before the `sys` module is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45692841/590335)

I have a similar use case to that described in the question - I need to get the python script name from within the usercustomize hook

however, sys.argv isn't populated at this time, and there's no documented way to get the script that is going to be executed.

using psutil allows getting the original command line

I'm looking for a reliable way to parse it the same way python does
(preferably using the same code that does the parsing for the python interpreter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27368717/2648811 (mentioned as a possible duplicate in the linked question)

Comment: no, it suggests another way of getting the raw command line, I'm looking for a reliable way to get the path to the script

parsing in "manually" is possible, but I rather not handle all edge cases

Comment: Have you experimented with using [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getouterframes) inside the `usercustomize` hook, to see if you can pull filename or arg data from the top of the call stack?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `__file__` variable give you what you want?

P.S. - sorry, not enough rep to comment

Comment: No. It's populated with the filename of the usercustomize file